# JQuery Dynamic cell color based on the row below

Tags: jquery, mysql

I have a table dynamically generated from a MySQL table and I would like the cell to change color based on the target below. Let's say the month of `Apr`, the target is `602` and the result is `435` so below `602` would be green. But let's take `Aug` for example. The result is slightly above target which is yellow. But `Jun` it's way too much above the target so I want to me it red.

```
Month   |   Apr     May     Jun     Jul     Aug
---------------------------------------------------
Result  |   435     495     943     735     617
Target  |   602     592     585     584     610
```

I have an example here in JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/D5TQy/ but I don't know how to make it read from the row below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to modify the way i get the variable `cellAbove`, but take a look at this: (http://jsfiddle.net/D5TQy/3/)

```
var cell = $('tr').last().find('td');
var cellAbove = $('tr').first().find('td');
var threshold= 100;    //defines what is `too much` difference

cell.each(function() {
    var column = $(this).index();

    var cell_value = $(this).text();
    var valueAbove = cellAbove.eq(column).text();

    //red
    if (cell_value - valueAbove > threshold) {
        $(this).addClass('veryOutsideFromTarget');
    }

    //yellow
    else if ((cell_value - valueAbove > 0)) {
        $(this).addClass('outsideTarget');
    } 

    //green
    else{
        $(this).addClass('insideTarget');
    }
});
```

**Notes:**
Make use of classes instead of modifying the background inline style. This way is even more simple to read and understand the code.

I modified the logic of your conditions and this way makes more sense.

Comment: Very nice but let's say I have it vertical in column instead of rows, how would you do it?

Comment: You should open a new question for that. This question refers to rows.